# How to use subquery table alias in WHERE clause in MySQL

Tags: mysql, subquery

```
SELECT invoice_id, sum_amount
FROM (SELECT invoice_id, SUM(amount) AS sum_amount
      FROM invoice
      GROUP BY invoice_id) AS TEMP_TABLE
WHERE sum_amount in (SELECT MAX(sum_amount) 
                     FROM TEMP_TABLE);
```

When I tried to use the TEMP_TABLE, an error occurred and said TEMP_TABLE doesn't exist. Why doesn't it work? I think the execution order is "FROM" then "WHERE", the table alias has been created at that time.

Comment: i know there are other ways to do that. but any explanation why this one is invalid? Thanks!

Comment: You would need a CTE (common table expression) to reuse a derived table alias and mysql doesn't support CTE's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't calculate max for the previously calculated alias in sub query alternatively you can rewrite your query as

```
SELECT a.invoice_id, SUM(a.amount) AS sum_amount,
c.max_amount
FROM invoice AS a
CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT MAX(sum_amount) max_amount FROM(
          SELECT invoice_id, SUM(amount) AS sum_amount
          FROM invoice
          GROUP BY invoice_id
      ) b
) c
GROUP BY a.invoice_id
HAVING sum_amount = c.max_amount
```

I have created a sample demo for testing purpose

Sample data

```
INSERT INTO invoice
    (`invoice_id`, `amount`)
VALUES
    (1, 10),
    (2, 5),
    (2, 5),
    (3, 1),
    (4, 2);
```

In above query you can see maximum sum of amount for invoice is 10 so invoice_id =>1,2 should be returned  1 has amount of 10 and two entries for invoice_id => 2 (5+5 = 10) is also 10 ,3 and 4 should not be included in result set sample output

```
invoice_id  sum_amount  max_amount
1           10          10
2           10          10
```

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/230b1/2)

Comment: thanks. any links for explaining why the alias cannot be used?

Comment: @llian i can't find any best link to send you but a alias calculated alias can be used for filter but not again for calculation either you need to put whole query or you have to use sub selects